# Not able to get backup of SVN repository

Tags: android, svn, version-control, backup

I want to have `svn` directory backup in local system and `import` in `AndroidStudio`

So I am using this command :

```
 svnadmin hotcopy ~/svn_directory ~/Desktop/
```

This is giving error :

```
svnadmin: E000002: Can't open file '/home/kushalgandhi/svn_directory/format': No such file or directory
```

I checked in **svn_directory** but there is no **format** folder. Why the command is searching for `format` named folder which is not existing?

What is reason for above error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
svn export ~/svn_directory ~/Desktop/
```

This command creates a clean copy of SVN code in `~/Desktop/` directory. Clean copy means the output do not have `svn` controlling files (like Green mark [image] or Red mark [image])

Thank you